# splitting a json object into arrays of keys and values in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is my code where imp receiving a json object inside my tenant of type Tenant from my api and I want to separate it into keys and values inside my function `tenantParser()` but when I do `console.log(displayedValues)` and  `console.log(displayedKeys)` it show array `length = 0` I don't know where I'm getting wrong with my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiServiceService } from 'src/app/Services/api-service.service';
import { Tenant } from 'src/app/class/tenant';
    
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-datawrangling',
  templateUrl: './datawrangling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datawrangling.component.css']
})

export class DatawranglingComponent implements OnInit {
  
  displayedValues:any=[];
  displayedKeys:any=[]
  tenants!: Tenant[];
  tags: any;

  constructor(private apiService:ApiServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.apiService.sendGetRequest().subscribe ( data => {
       this.tenants = data; 
      console.log(this.tenants);
    });
     
     console.log(this.displayedValues)

  } 

  tenantParser(){
   this.tenants.forEach((element:any )=> {
      
      this.displayedValues=Object.keys(element);
     this.displayedKeys.push(Object.values(element));
   });

    this.ngOnInit()

    alert(this.displayedData)   
  }

}
```

Comment: Where and when are you calling `tenantParser()`? You won't get anything in `displayedValues` the way you've put. You are printing the values before the data has a chance to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call tenantParser() after the completion of the request, so IN the subscribe(). tenantParser() should not call ngOnInit.

Also the assignment of Keys and Values is different in your code. Is that your intention?